# Rock, paper, scissors game. Writing a print statement that works

Tags: python, computer-science

Here is my code:

```
from random import*
from myro import*
from math import*

def computerChoice():
   computer = randint(0,2)
   if (computer == 0):
     choice = "rock"
   elif(computer == 1):
     choice = "paper"
   else:
     choice = "scissors"

  return choice

def userGuess():
     print " R = Rock"
     print " P = Paper"
     print " S = Scissors"

     userChoice = raw_input("Enter R, P, or S: ")

     return userChoice

def calculate(userChoice, choice):

    userNameWins = 0
    computerWins = 0
    draws = 0

    if(userChoice == "R" and choice == "paper"):
       speak("scribbler wins")
       computerWins = computerWins + 1
    elif(userChoice== "R" and choice == "scissors"):
       speak( "you win")
        userNameWins = userNameWins + 1
    elif(userChoice== "P" and choice == "rock"):
       speak("you win")
       userNameWins = userNameWins + 1
    elif(userChoice== "P" and choice == "scissors"):
       speak("scribbler wins")
       computerWins = computerWins + 1
    elif(userChoice == "S" and choice == "rock"):
       speak("scribbler wins")
       computerWins = computerWins + 1
    elif(userChoice == "S" and choice == "paper"):
       speak("you win")
       userNameWins = userNameWins + 1
    else:
       speak("Draw")
       draws = draws + 1

    return userNameWins, computerWins, draws

def printResults(userNameWins, computerWins, draws)
    # insert code for print statement

def main():

    for x in range (5):
         speak("Rock Papers Scissors ")
         userChoice = userGuess()
         choice = computerChoice()
         calculate(userChoice,choice)
    printResults (userNameWins, computerWins, draws)
```

I get an error when I try to define some variables and I don't know why.
I need a function that properly prints the results returned by `calculate()`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What does "I get an error when I try to define some variables" mean? What error? What's the traceback? What is the code you're writing that "tr[ies] to define some variables"?

Comment: I'm making a solution at the moment, hopefully it should help.

Comment: @dansalmo: If you're going to propose code golf to replace parts of the code that the OP has already written, rather than the parts they're asking about, without any comment… you might want to make them actually work.

Comment: ['Tie', 'I win', 'You win'][randint(0, 2) - 'rRpPsS'.index(raw_input("Enter R, P, or S: "))/2]

Comment: I hate when people paste stuff that does not work. Sorry for that.  It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The part you're asking for is trivial. Since you didn't give us the desired output format, I'll guess at it, and hopefully you can fix it to match the way you want it to look:

```
def printResults(userNameWins, computerWins, draws)
    print('user won {} times, computer won {} times, and players drew {} times'
          .format(userNameWins, computerWins, draws))
```

However, your code isn't going to work, for at least two reasons.

---

First, you call this:

```
calculate(userChoice,choice)
```

… which returns the 3 values you want, but you never *store* them anywhere. In particular, you don't store them, or anything else, in variables named `userNameWins`, `computerWins`, and `draws`. So, this like will get a `NameError`:

```
printResults (userNameWins, computerWins, draws)
```

---

Second, you're looping 5 times over a function that, each time, returns a full set of values, but you're only calling `printResults` once, not 5 times. I'm not sure what you're intending here, but most likely, either you need to move `printResults` into the loop, or you need to add code that sums up the results across all the loops.

Answer (score 0):

sorry about the wait but hopefully this solution is of help to you.

```
from random import randint
#from myro import *
choice = None
userChoice = None
userNameWins = 0
computerWins = 0
draws = 0

def computerChoice():
   global choice
   computer = randint(0,2)
   if (computer == 0):
     choice = "rock"
   elif(computer == 1):
     choice = "paper"
   else:
     choice = "scissors"
   print "Scribbler selected " + choice
   return choice

def userGuess():
     global userChoice
     print " R = Rock"
     print " P = Paper"
     print " S = Scissors"

     userChoice = raw_input("Enter R, P, or S: ")

     return userChoice

def calculate(userChoice, choice):
    global userNameWins
    global computerWins
    global draws
    if(userChoice == "R" and choice == "paper"):
       print("scribbler wins")
       computerWins = computerWins + 1
    elif(userChoice== "R" and choice == "scissors"):
       print( "you win")
       userNameWins = userNameWins + 1
    elif(userChoice== "P" and choice == "rock"):
       print("you win")
       userNameWins = userNameWins + 1
    elif(userChoice== "P" and choice == "scissors"):
       print("scribbler wins")
       computerWins = computerWins + 1
    elif(userChoice == "S" and choice == "rock"):
       print("scribbler wins")
       computerWins = computerWins + 1
    elif(userChoice == "S" and choice == "paper"):
       print("you win")
       userNameWins = userNameWins + 1
    else:
       print("Draw")
       draws = draws + 1

def printResults():
    print "You won " + str(userNameWins) + " times"
    print "Scribbler won " + str(computerWins) + " times"
    print "There were " + str(draws) + " draws"
    if (userNameWins > computerWins):
       print "You win overall"
    elif (userNameWins < computerWins):
       print "Scribbler wins overall"
    else:
       print "It was a dead heat"

def main():
    global userChoice
    global choice
    for x in range (5):
         print ("Rock Papers Scissors ")
         userChoice = userGuess()
         choice = computerChoice()
         calculate(userChoice,choice)
    printResults ()
main()
```

I didn't have `myro` installed so I used `print` instead to display the results. Before you weren't saving the variables for the results anywhere so I made a global variable so that it can store the variables. Also I completed the `printResults` function.